# Map array values to the ruby hash key

Tags: ruby

here i have the sample code , mapping array to hash and appending hash to array but expected output is missing the array value

```
data = {"a"=>5,"b"=>["e","f"]}
data1 = [44,55]
s = []
data1.each_with_index do |i,index|
    a = data1[index]
    data["b"] = i
    s << data
end
p s
```

output:

```
[{"a"=>5, "b"=>55}, {"a"=>5, "b"=>55}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"a"=>5, "b"=>44}, {"a"=>5, "b"=>55}]
```

Comment: Why e and f what's the relation? You gave 44 but 45 is in the result? What kind of question is this?

Comment: thanks for correcting me its a 44

Comment: What is e and f?

Comment: that are just strings i want to replace with integers

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are putting the same object reference into each of your array elements. Think of it as putting two keys to the same locker in two different places. If you change the stuff in the locker, both keys will open it, and they will both see the same stuff. So, when you change the value of `'b'`, you change it for the object in both array elements, because they're the same object.

The solution is to start your block by creating a copy of the `data` object, changing its `'b'` value, and putting the result into the resulting array.

I've also changed your `each_with_index` to `map`, because `map` is best to use when you are transforming the values in the array. Also, you don't need to have the index available in your block; you're just running through the array elements without caring which element you're working with while you're working with it.

```
  data = {"a"=>5,"b"=>["e","f"]}
  data1 = [44,55]
  s = []
  data1.map do |num|
    the_copy = data.clone
    the_copy['b'] = num
    s << the_copy
  end
  p s
```